# Python CSV is not Defined

Tags: python, indentation

I am using the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup (open("43rd-congress.htm"))

final_link = soup.p.a
final_link.decompose()


f = csv.writer(open("43rd_congress_all.csv", "w"))
f.writerow(["Name","Years","Position","Party", "State", "Congress", "Link"])
trs = soup.find_all('tr')

for tr in trs:
    for link in tr.find_all('a'):
        fulllink = link.get ('href')

        print fulllink #print in terminal to verify results

        tds = tr.find_all("td")

        try: #we are using "try" because the table is not well formatted. This allows the program to continue after encountering an error.
            names = str(tds[0].get_text()) # This structure isolate the item by its column in the table and converts it into a string.
            years = str(tds[1].get_text())
            positions = str(tds[2].get_text())
            parties = str(tds[3].get_text())
            states = str(tds[4].get_text())
            congress = tds[5].get_text()

        except:
            print "bad tr string"
            continue #This tells the computer to move on to the next item after it encounters an error

        print names, years, positions, parties, states, congress
            f.writerow([names, years, posiitons, parties, states, congress, fullLink])
```

And I get the following error. **On line 34 (which is the last line).
IndentationError: Unexpected indent.** I am using this tutorial here. http://jeriwieringa.com/blog/2012/11/04/beautiful-soup-tutorial-part-1/

I suspect that it is a problem with indentations.

Comment: Have you worked through a simple Python program before? Indentation is kind of a big deal (with Python)

Comment: I have worked through two. One by codeacademy and the other by LPTHW.

Comment: You'll probably get an error in the last line because 'positions' is spelled wrong as well.

Answer (score 4):

The error is very evident.

```
    print names, years, positions, parties, states, congress
        f.writerow([names, years, posiitons, parties, states, congress, fullLink])
```

should be

```
    print names, years, positions, parties, states, congress
    f.writerow([names, years, posiitons, parties, states, congress, fullLink])
```

Python does not like unexpected indentation of code, and the `f.writerow` should have the same level of indentation as the `print` statement.

Read more on [indentation here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html). I would recommend you not proceeding any further until you understand this completely, as it is one of the most basic, and important concepts in python.

To fix the csv issue,

You need to

```
import csv
```

at the beginning of the file.

Comment: I tried that fix then I go to an error on line 9. Which states csv is not defined.

Comment: @Rob, CSV is a module that has to be imported

Comment: @RobB. Not to offend you, but please go through a Python Tutorial (a more basic one) before you try to parse XML.

Comment: None taken. I appreciate all the help I can get. I thought I had a fairly good idea about indentations.

Comment: Could you please edit the post to show me how you fixed the code? I am definitely reading the tutorial.

Comment: for `csv` undefined, just add `import csv` at the beginning of your file. Before `from bs4 import ..` `csv` is a builtin python module.

Comment: I made the changes you recommended the code you see is the code I have, but I get the names are undefined on the last line. I read through the indentation tutorials...they told me what I already knew, but I think I need something for bigger loops. Thanks for the help

Comment: You have a typo: `posiitons` should be `positions` and also `fullLink` and `fulllink` are not the same local variable.